# Loop over state and check if object exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have some code that seems to work, just not correctly. I have an `onChange` handler that sends up a key and value to `setState()` of its parent component.

```
_onAttributeChange(key, value) {
    const changes = this.state.changes;
    const pushObj = {key: key, value: value};
    console.log(pushObj);
    if (changes.length === 0) {
        this.setState({changes: changes.concat([pushObj])});
    } else {
        changes.forEach(change => {
            if (change.key === key) {
                console.log('Update');
            } else {
                console.log('No update');
                this.setState({changes: changes.concat([pushObj])});
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

You can see from this code that I am creating an object based on the key value parameters that will look like `{key: 1, value: 'Some Value'}`. The goal is to concat that to the array if the array is of length 0. That part works fine. The forEach is where I'm having issues. My goal is to loop through the state array, check if the change.key coming in matches a key in the array, and if it does I want to perform an update, otherwise I want to concat once again to add that change to the array.

So 2 questions:

- Firstly, when the first change comes in, the loop works properly, and will just console log `Update` for each consecutive change with the same key (i.e. 1). When another change comes in, it works properly at first and concats it to the array, but then any consecutive change with the key of 2, it will fire the console log of Update AND the else clause.
- Secondly, how can I update the change while looping over the array without mutating the state directly?

Comment: Did my answer help at all? If it did, please consider marking it as "accepted". If not, let me know how I can help.

Comment: @Chris Sorry about that Chris. I actually came down with a stomach flu the day before asking this so I never even got back to check it until the other day. I have accepted your answer as it definitely is the solution!

Comment: Not a problem. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer should be quite simple really; just work on a temporary copy of the state and once you're done replace your actual state with the copy.

```
_onAttributeChange(key, value) {
  let changes = this.state.changes.slice();
  const pushObj = {key: key, value: value};
  console.log(pushObj);
  if (changes.length === 0) {
    changes = changes.concat([pushObj]);
  } else {
    changes.forEach(change => {
      if (change.key === key) {
        console.log('Update');
      } else {
        console.log('No update');
        changes = changes.concat([pushObj]);
      }
    });
  }
  this.setState({changes: changes});
}
```

The problem you were having with the consecutive changes is most likely related to the asynchronous nature of `setState()`. Not only does each such call result in an unnecessary re-render but it will also, almost certainly, update your state in an unwanted way.

Have a look at what the official React documentation says about [**setState()**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

So basically it is likely returning the "old" state value when you actually want the updated one from the previous iteration in your loop.

---

Another very important thing to note here is that you need to create a ***copy*** of the state property you're working on. Otherwise you'd be making changes to the state directly, which might work, but is discouraged.

So basically always do:

```
//To copy an array
let arr = this.state.myArray;  //wrong. arr still references myArray
let arr = this.state.myArray.slice();  //correct

//To copy an object
let obj = this.state.myObject;  //wrong. obj still references myObject
let obj = Object.assign({}, this.state.myObject);  //correct
```

More info on MDN for [**slice()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [**Object.assign()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Also, use `const` sparingly. Only use it when a variable **must** be immutable.

---

**TL;DR** - Always do all the logic first, *then* commit your state changes.

Comment: It should be `=` instead of `:` in the line after "No update".

Comment: @squGEIm Good eye. Thanks.